# Проблема с отборажением объекта на iphone 5

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть js код который позволяет перемещать элемент `<div id="container_move">` как на компьютерах, так и на сенсорных экранах, внутри него находится элемент `<img class="bv" id="screen" src="">` перспективу которого можно менять при помощи четырёх элементов `<circle cx="" cy="" r="30" class="control-point">` расставленные по углам картинки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но есть проблема, когда человек запускает страницу с iphone 5 у него пропадает картинка, при этом элементы "circle" остаются и когда человека начинает передвигать элементы "circle" картинка появляется и работает нормально.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На iphone 6 и андроидах работает всё нормально.

Как решить эту проблему?

Полный пример кода:http://jsfiddle.net/kbQPW/74/